What made scientists think that chemistry is reducible to physics and when did that happen?
What I mean by reduction in this context is the following: suppose you are analyzing a simple event like one object striking another in space. At the macroscopic level one, you can describe this event in terms of two masses in collision and the resulting motion as a consequence of the conservation of momentum and energy. At the microscopic level you could describe this in terms of the atoms of one object coming into proximity with the atoms of the other object and repelling them by the negative outer charges of the atoms, where it is the momentum of the atoms that matter. A holistic view of this double state of affairs would say that the only distinction between the two descriptions is what they are useful for. A reductionist view of this state of affairs would say that the macroscopic description, while true, is a mere consequence of the microscopic description, that the microscopic description is the real underlying explanation.
However, "explanation" is something of a distraction here because what we are really talking about is causes. Explanation suggests something that is accessible to humans, while causes are real physical things that may or may not be accessible to humans. So to say that a macroscopic event is reducible to a microscopic event is to say that the real physical causes are the microscopic causes. The macroscopic cause is just an aggregate event that we perceive as the cause. In the previous two centuries there was a long period when scientists pretty much just assumed that all real physical causes are reducible to forces acting on atoms or subatomic particles or fields or quantum objects or the like. That is what I mean by "reducible to physics".
The idea that all of nature other than minds can be reduced to physics goes back as far as Descartes, but it wasn't that widely accepted until the 20th century. Historically, the move to reduce biology to physics and chemistry was motivated in large part by the medical research of the second half of the 19th century--research such as synthesizing organic compounds, the discovery that electricity plays a part in nervous impulses, etc.
But what motivated the move to view chemistry as reducible to physics? Did the idea take over immediately during the enthusiasm following the publication of Newton's Principia? Was it the development of chemical atomic theory? Was it the development of the Bohr model of the atom? When and why did scientists just start assuming that chemistry is reducible to physics?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@JimmyJames, what do you mean by "physical reality"? If you mean "all of nature", then yes, chemistry is part of the study of all of nature, but no, physics is not the study of all of nature. If you mean the kinds of things that physics has historically studied such as forces, simple mechanical events, light, magnetism, and the like, then it is not obvious that chemistry is reducible to that.

Why are you asking here, instead of History of Science and Mathematics?


But what motivated the move to view chemistry as reducible to physics? ... When and why did scientists just start assuming that chemistry is reducible to physics?

It's confusing to say "reducible to physics", rather than saying being explainable in a unified model of matter.
While the atomic model allowed to mathematically unify different disciplines, this does not mean that before the atomic model existed, researchers of those disciplines did not think or hope that their research could one day be unified.
Scientists never "just start assuming" anything, instead they invented and discovered experiments that did not allow any other reasonable view of nature than that atoms and their properties underly and explain observable nature (other than mind and miracles), and also that an atomic model sufficiently explain all experiment outcomes.
It's just a matter of definitions to call the atomic model "physics", it might be less confusing to say that all natural sciences are reduceable in theory to atomic models in the sense that they do not need to assume any other element or force in nature.
The second way the claim is confusing is that laws of chemistry are not currently formulated in formulas that derive all chemical observations to atomic properties. In that sense, chemistry still does not reduce to physics, even if chemistry is based on an atomic understanding of matter.
The processes chemistry describes are about the interactions of larger quantities of matter that might never be mathematically reduceable to atomic properties and laws. But that's more of a "mathematical problem" that the behavior of many independently moving things cannot easily be captured in mathematical formulas. As an example see the three body problem of astronomy, showing how hard it is (currently) to mathematically calculate motions when more than one (or two) things are involved. In that sense chemistry could be seen as the study of "many-body" problems, with atoms and molecules.

I don't agree that "explainable in a unified model of matter" means the same as "reducible to physics".

@DavidGudeman I cannot know what definition you wish to see applied unless you provide it in the question. I don't think the word "reducible" has any single definition, nor does the phrase "reducible to physics" have any clear meaning. It would be more surprising if by coincidence we had thought of the same exact meaning.

"nor does the phrase "reducible to physics" have any clear meaning" What is unclear about it?  It means that chemistry can be explained in terms of fundamental physics, but physics (in general) cannot be explained in terms of chemistry. Or in other words, the fundamental 'laws' of chemistry are the 'laws' of physics.

I've added a preliminary description to explain what I mean by "reducible to physics".

Incidentally, another problem with this answer is suggested by "Scientists never 'just start assuming' anything". This suggests that you are working from an unrealistic, idealized view of science, while I am asking about actual historical science.

@JimmyJames: that's your opinion on what it means, and I never said it's not possible to have an opinion if what it means. I am saying any two reasonable people can easily disagree about the meaning of those words. So giving me your interpretation does not change anything.

@tkruse And because you are aware that there is a clear, well-understood meaning of the phrase doesn't change the fact that there's a clear, well-understood meaning.

The reducibility phenomenon was set into motion when it was discovered that quantum mechanical calculations yielded the size, shape, and location of the electronic energy levels (orbitals) that surround all atoms.
Those orbitals are responsible for all the various types of interatomic bonding that can occur between atoms. Furthermore, the number of electrons that can share a given orbital is also due to quantum mechanics and determines the chemical behavior of atoms interacting with one another.
"Quantum chemistry" had its beginnings in the early 1970s when computers powerful enough to perform the QM calculations on systems as complicated as multi-atom molecules first became available.
If QM did not exist, discretization of confined electron energy levels would not exist and neither would the Pauli exclusion principle. This means atoms as we know them would not exist and neither would the discipline of chemistry. By the way, without QM, the universe as we know it would not exist, and neither would its inhabitants.

+1 I'm curious why you don't see the advent of reduction sooner with the advent of the quantification that inheres in modern atomic theory reducing chemicals to atoms. Atoms serve as the ontological basis for physical chemistry which bridges the gap between physical motion of particles and the properties that arise from their aggregation as substances.  To do violence to Charle's and Boyle's and Lavosier's ideas, isn't PV=nRT the advent of the reduction of chemistry to physics?

@JD But what makes a sodium atom, say, have totally different properties than a chlorine atom? Until scientists understood about orbitals they just had to assume that they were different because...well, because they were different.

@JD, this is the "reducible in practice" point.  The "theoretically reducible" point came much earlier, but there's a huge gap between "I think we can describe chemistry in terms of physics" and actually having the measurements, formulas, and computing power to show how two hydrogen atoms combine to form a molecule.

The concept you are referring to is the "Unity of Science" thesis.  SEP's article https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-unity/ spells out:

Kant articulated unity of science through reason and pure mathematics, dismissing chemistry of the time as just systematizing, and biology as requiring teleology.  With the Atomic Theory and electron valences, chemistry would make the cut per Kant.
Comte articulated the tiered structure of the sciences in 1830-42
Carnap articulated the reductionism of everything to physics, following the structure of Comte's tiers, in two works 1928-32.
Anti-reductionist pluralism, where sciences are a non-reductive family of disciplines that share a methodology was counter-argued by Carnap's fellow member of the Vienna Circle Neurath in 1934
Ernst Nagel in 1961 articulated an explicit theory of reduction (SEP). About half of chemistry today satisfies this criteria.  The other half, and most of the rest of science, face structural issues that suggest they never will satisfy it.  See SEP on Chemical Reduction: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chemistry/#CheRed

The consequence of the failure to complete global reductionism has been the abandonment of the Unity of Sciences thesis by the majority of philosophers of science.  Pluralism is now the dominant paradigm.  See SEP's Scientific Reductionism, section 5:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/
Chemistry is half reduced, and may get incrementally more reduced over time, but will never be fully reduced to physics.

Physics describes electrons and their valence shells; the manipulation of electrons and their valence shells is chemistry.  Thus, why isn't chemistry reduced to physics (even though practically it's easier to "do chemistry" at the macro level, instead of the very complicated physics calculations?

@RonJohn Half of chemistry reduces to physics.  The other half has not reduced to valences and thermodynamics.

If it's not based on valences and thermodynamics, then what's the theoretical basis?

@RonJohn -- Science is an empirical bottom-up process, not an analytic one.  Observations are explained by hypotheses, and if the hypotheses pass stress testing, become theories, which are inferred to be real per indirect realism.  Half of this set of chemistry theories does not reduce to physics theories.  The "theoretical basis" of the rest of chemistry, and the rest of science which does not reduce to chemistry or physics is Popperian science principles.  That this is not a coherent set is -- what bottom-up science leads to.

That reactions happens even though known theories and laws (valence count, various bonding methods, electronegativity, etc) say they shouldn't is pretty amazing in 2024.  Do you have any examples?

@RonJohn -- however hard you wish it were so, chemistry does not reduce to physics, biology to chemistry, or psychology to biology.  Rhetoric and venom will not change the world to the way you wish it were.

Asking for examples to demonstrate philosophical assertions is certainly valid, and definitely not (yet) venomous.

@RonJohn You have been provided links to the considered judgement of the expert community.  There are examples in those links.  The theory of reduction is also there, and reasons why it cannot be satisfied in principle.  There are phenomena in our universe which do not depend on the details of the substrate.  If physicalism has any hope of ever closing, it will need to incorporate a theory of strong emergence, and top down causation.

I've come to the considered opinion that philosophers are not experts in science.  That's the only good thing to come out of this discussion.

@RonJohn  Scientists are not likely to be MORE open to your "wish it were so" than philosophers!  The scientists publishing "Foundations of Chemistry" are pluralists too:  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10698-020-09378-0    https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10698-018-9315-x
